# Mount Drive on Boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have a secondary hard drive and wanted to to mount the drive to the `/home/josh/plexmedia2` folder.
In order to to do that I run the below command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/josh/plexmedia2
```

However, when I reboot the server, the drive becomes unmounted. How can I make the drive mount itself on boot?

Answer (score 1):

Put your command in a script and save the script in /etc/init.d directory. Giving the necessary permission.